# How to remove arrow tooltip in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

**This is my code** : I used https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/

```
import React from "react"
import {OverlayTrigger, Tooltip} from "react-bootstrap"
import { HeaderPrintContainer, Button} from "../share/header-button-style"
```

This is value in tooltip.

```
const tooltipLove = (
  <Tooltip id="tooltipLove">
     I Love You
  </Tooltip>
)

const tooltipHate = (
  <Tooltip id="tooltipHate">
     I Hate You
  </Tooltip>
)
```

This is Button when hover.It's will show Tooltip

```
const ButtonLove = () => (
  <HeaderPrintContainer>
    <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={tooltipLove}>
      <Button bsStyle="default">Love</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
    <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={tooltipHate}>
      <Button bsStyle="default">Hate</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  </HeaderPrintContainer>
)

export default ButtonLove;
```

I want remove arrow in tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS for this add following line on your CSS file:

```
.tooltip-arrow {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: how to do it in module css?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to inspect your code in some browser

Just add this style to your style sheet:

```
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

If its not working just try this one:

```
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: transparent !important;
}
```

What we are trying to do is just overriding the predefined CSS

During Inspect

[image]

Just make if display: none or just make the colour transparent